# How manage "wkhtmltopdf" on .NET Core Api on IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, wkhtmltopdf, rotativa

I have a .NET Core 3.1 API calling wkhtmltopdf.exe to generate a PDF (using RotativaCore wrapper).
Its working fine with moderate usage... The problem when I have too many request at same time ...
Several 'wkhtmltopdf.exe" will stuck on Windows processes and I start to get several errors:

```
QEventDispatcher: Failed to create QEventDispatcherWin32 internal window: 87 Qt: INTERNALL ERROR: failed to install GetMessage hook This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

How can I handle that?

Comment: Have you try to use this library ?
https://github.com/fpanaccia/Wkhtmltopdf.NetCore

Comment: Not yet, do you think it can solve my issue?

Comment: I've read some comments in the past about the use of this library on server side projects.

Comment: Another approach could be to create a _queue_ via a DB table of all the requests and a process that create/destroy the instances of wkhtmltopdf, so you can control the number of process created and destroyed.